# Data validation with JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, validation

I want to perform data validation while JOptionPane.I found the following approach but i am not really satisfied with it

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class ValidateJOptionPane {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number: ");
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z,a-z,&%$#@!()*^]");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
                if (m.find()) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter only numbers");
                }
        }
}
```

It would have been better and more sensible to use the regex to detect the characters that can be entered rather than testing for characters that can't be entered.

Is there a better and simpler way to do data validation with JOptionPane ? . I feel regex is overkill here.Correct me if i am wrong:P

P.S i am a beginner with Java

Answer (score 4):

The long answer is, use `DocumentFilter`, see [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more details.

The problem with this is, you need to take control, you can't rely on the "simple", "helper" functionality provided by `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`, as you need access to the text field been used to prompt the user...

For example...

[image: Filter input]

The following examples uses a (slightly) modified version of the `PatternFilter` from [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter.FilterBypass;

public class ValidateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
        ((AbstractDocument) field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new PatternFilter(p));
        int option = ask("Enter number:", field);
        if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("You have entered " + field.getText());
        }
    }

    public static int ask(String label, JComponent comp) {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel(label));
        panel.add(comp);

        return JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, label, 
                        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);

    }

    public static class PatternFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        // Useful for every kind of input validation !
        // this is the insert pattern
        // The pattern must contain all subpatterns so we can enter characters into a text component !
        private Pattern pattern;

        public PatternFilter(Pattern p) {
            pattern = p;
        }

        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr)
                        throws BadLocationException {

            String newStr = fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength()) + string;
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(newStr);
            if (m.matches()) {
                super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
            } else {
            }
        }

        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset,
                        int length, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws
                        BadLocationException {

            if (length > 0) {
                fb.remove(offset, length);
            }
            insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
        }
    }

}
```

Now, with a little clever design, you could write a simple helper class which built all this internally and provided a nice `askFor(String label, Pattern p)` style method that could return a `String` (or `null` if the user canceled the operation)

Answer (score 1):

As you said *"It would have been better and more sensible to use the regex to detect the characters that can be entered rather than testing for characters that can't be entered."*
So you can just do the reverse checking then :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class ValidateJOptionPane {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number: ");
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]*$");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
            if (!m.find()) { // if pattern doesn't match (not found) 
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter only numbers");
            }
    }
  }
```

`[0-9]` means digit 0-9 while `*` means some spaces

Comment: Also can you please explain your regex ...i used `[0-9]+`