# How to validate Regular Expression in real time on jtextbox?

Tags: java, regex, swing, netbeans-8, keylistener

I'm trying to validate/filter my jtextbox wwith this Regex:

```java
^(([A-za-z]+[\s]{1}[A-za-z]+)|([A-Za-z]+))$
```

I want to filter two names with one space.

Tried using `keytyped` and `keyreleased`, but it just does not work (won't let me write anything on the textbox) and `e.consume()` does not work.

```java
boolean StrCheck(String Exp,String str) {
            return Pattern.matches(Exp,str);
            }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == jTextField) {
            String regexp = "^(([A-za-z]+[\s]{1}[A-za-z]+)|([A-Za-z]+))$";
            if (jTextField.getText().length() == 25) {
                e.consume();
            } if (StrCheck(regexp,jTextField.getText())){

            }else {
                e.consume();
            }
```

I've been searching, but the only possible answer I got, was to create a Documentlistene BUT can't find any example or how actually do it and make it work.

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790820/jtextfield-with-regex-applied-wont-accept-value-until-after-the-document-is-app/28790963#28790963) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418243/data-validation-with-joptionpane/25418345#25418345)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `KeylListener`, neither `DocumentListener` will work. In most of this kind of cases you would need to use a [DocumentFilter.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) Before you do though, take a look on [how to use formatted textfields.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) It might be enough for you. If it does not, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28790963/6579265) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping I tried using the PatternFilter, it works just don't let me add a White Space, maybe something wrong with my regex, I'll be using the formatted textfields in others jtextbox so thanks.